# How to store the data like category in ios

Tags: ios, list, nsdictionary, jsonresponse

I'm working one shopping app and I have response data's like All Categories for Example Main category has men, women,kids etc. Each one has sub-Category like T-shirts, shirts, footwear etc and that also have some sub category(ex.footwear) casual Shoes,formal shoes,sandals etc.
So how can I store this response and how to show one particular category?

This is my Response

```
{  
   "success":true,
   "category":[  
      {  
         "category_id":"74",
         "parent_id":"0",
         "name":"Grocery",
         "image":"catalog\/Rice.jpg",
         "top":"1",
         "column":"1",
         "sort_order":"0",
         "status":"1",
         "date_added":"2015-03-25 11:26:46",
         "date_modified":"2015-04-20 11:04:29",
         "description":"&lt;p&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;",
         "meta_title":"Grocery",
         "meta_description":"",
         "meta_keyword":"",
         "store_id":"0",
         "subcategory":[  
            {  
               "category_id":"75",
               "parent_id":"74",
               "name":"Dals &amp; Pulses",
               "image":"catalog\/0004620_dm-gram-dal-1kg.png",
               "top":"0",
               "column":"0",
               "sort_order":"1",
               "status":"1",
               "date_added":"2015-03-25 11:42:20",
               "date_modified":"2015-04-20 11:08:24",
               "description":"&lt;p&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;",
               "meta_title":"Dals &amp; Pulses",
               "meta_description":"",
               "meta_keyword":"",
               "store_id":"0"
            },
            {  
               "category_id":"76",
               "parent_id":"74",
               "name":"Dry Fruits &amp; Nuts",
               "image":"catalog\/almonds.jpg",
               "top":"0",
               "column":"0",
               "sort_order":"2",
               "status":"1",
               "date_added":"2015-03-25 12:17:39",
               "date_modified":"2015-04-20 11:08:11",
               "description":"&lt;p&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;",
               "meta_title":"Dry Fruits &amp; Nuts",
               "meta_description":"",
               "meta_keyword":"",
               "store_id":"0"
            },
            {  
               "category_id":"77",
               "parent_id":"74",
               "name":"Edible Oil &amp; Ghees",
               "image":"catalog\/oil.jpg",
               "top":"0",
               "column":"0",
               "sort_order":"3",
               "status":"1",
               "date_added":"2015-03-25 15:06:06",
               "date_modified":"2015-04-16 18:03:13",
               "description":"&lt;p&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;",
               "meta_title":"Edible Oil &amp; Ghees",
               "meta_description":"",
               "meta_keyword":"",
               "store_id":"0"
            },
            {  
               "category_id":"78",
               "parent_id":"74",
               "name":"Atta &amp; Flour",
               "image":"catalog\/aashirvaad-atta-whole-wheat-noworry.jpg",
               "top":"0",
               "column":"0",
               "sort_order":"5",
               "status":"1",
               "date_added":"2015-03-25 16:27:52",
               "date_modified":"2015-04-20 11:04:38",
               "description":"&lt;p&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;",
               "meta_title":"Atta &amp; Flour",
               "meta_description":"",
               "meta_keyword":"",
               "store_id":"0"
            },
            {  
               "category_id":"79",
               "parent_id":"74",
               "name":"Rice",
               "image":"catalog\/Rice.jpg",
               "top":"0",
               "column":"0",
               "sort_order":"6",
               "status":"1",
               "date_added":"2015-03-25 16:42:55",
               "date_modified":"2015-04-16 18:03:40",
               "description":"&lt;p&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;",
               "meta_title":"Rice",
               "meta_description":"",
               "meta_keyword":"",
               "store_id":"0"
            },
            {  
               "category_id":"80",
               "parent_id":"74",
               "name":"Salt &amp; Sugar",
               "image":"catalog\/Sugar.jpg",
               "top":"0",
               "column":"0",
               "sort_order":"7",
               "status":"1",
               "date_added":"2015-03-25 16:53:12",
               "date_modified":"2015-03-25 20:10:24",
               "description":"&lt;p&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;",
               "meta_title":"Salt &amp; Sugar",
               "meta_description":"",
               "meta_keyword":"",
               "store_id":"0"
            },
            {  
               "category_id":"81",
               "parent_id":"74",
               "name":"Millets",
               "image":"catalog\/Millets.JPG",
               "top":"0",
               "column":"0",
               "sort_order":"8",
               "status":"1",
               "date_added":"2015-03-25 17:02:57",
               "date_modified":"2015-04-16 18:04:09",
               "description":"&lt;p&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;",
               "meta_title":"Millets",
               "meta_description":"",
               "meta_keyword":"",
               "store_id":"0"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "category_id":"82",
         "parent_id":"0",
         "name":"chips",
         "image":null,
         "top":"1",
         "column":"1",
         "sort_order":"2",
         "status":"1",
         "date_added":"2015-03-27 18:31:51",
         "date_modified":"2015-04-24 00:01:47",
         "description":"&lt;p&gt;chips are crispy&lt;\/p&gt;",
         "meta_title":"chips",
         "meta_description":"",
         "meta_keyword":"",
         "store_id":"0",
         "subcategory":[  
            {  
               "category_id":"83",
               "parent_id":"82",
               "name":"lays",
               "image":"catalog\/cashew4.jpg",
               "top":"0",
               "column":"0",
               "sort_order":"1",
               "status":"1",
               "date_added":"2015-03-27 18:32:53",
               "date_modified":"2015-04-23 23:45:59",
               "description":"&lt;p&gt;lays&lt;\/p&gt;",
               "meta_title":"lays",
               "meta_description":"",
               "meta_keyword":"",
               "store_id":"0"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "category_id":"84",
         "parent_id":"0",
         "name":"Food Items",
         "image":"catalog\/slide.jpg",
         "top":"1",
         "column":"1",
         "sort_order":"3",
         "status":"1",
         "date_added":"2015-04-26 22:13:21",
         "date_modified":"2015-04-26 22:13:21",
         "description":"Food Items",
         "meta_title":"Food Items",
         "meta_description":"",
         "meta_keyword":"",
         "store_id":"0",
         "subcategory":"null"
      },
      {  
         "category_id":"86",
         "parent_id":"0",
         "name":"HouseHold",
         "image":"catalog\/aashirvaad-atta-whole-wheat-noworry.jpg",
         "top":"1",
         "column":"1",
         "sort_order":"5",
         "status":"1",
         "date_added":"2015-04-26 22:36:03",
         "date_modified":"2015-04-26 22:40:46",
         "description":"HouseHold",
         "meta_title":"HouseHold",
         "meta_description":"",
         "meta_keyword":"",
         "store_id":"0",
         "subcategory":"null"
      },
      {  
         "category_id":"85",
         "parent_id":"0",
         "name":"Bread &amp; Diary",
         "image":"catalog\/orid dhal 500gm.JPG",
         "top":"1",
         "column":"1",
         "sort_order":"6",
         "status":"1",
         "date_added":"2015-04-26 22:30:14",
         "date_modified":"2015-04-26 22:40:17",
         "description":"Bread &amp;amp; Diary",
         "meta_title":"Bread &amp; Diary",
         "meta_description":"",
         "meta_keyword":"",
         "store_id":"0",
         "subcategory":"null"
      },
      {  
         "category_id":"87",
         "parent_id":"0",
         "name":"Fruits &amp; Vegetables",
         "image":"catalog\/cashew4.jpg",
         "top":"1",
         "column":"1",
         "sort_order":"7",
         "status":"1",
         "date_added":"2015-04-26 22:41:52",
         "date_modified":"2015-04-26 22:41:52",
         "description":"Fruits &amp;amp; Vegetables",
         "meta_title":"Fruits &amp; Vegetables",
         "meta_description":"",
         "meta_keyword":"",
         "store_id":"0",
         "subcategory":"null"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Do you want to store the data in local variables or in local database i.e., sqlite?? How you want exactly? If possible show us sample response data

Comment: store in a local variable and i update the response

Answer (score 1):

You can create class "Clothes" in this class you will have properties like "category","subCategory","title","image". For "category" you can use typedef enum. If you want to save objects use CoreData, create an Entity with similar properties and save your data.